# Jquery : how to add attributs dynamically with the function .attr()

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, attributes

I need to add my attributes dynamically to my input but it dosen't works.

- this.nomRoot is the name of the component here 'input'.
- this.lstAttr is an Array with the attributs like 'name' or 'checked'.
- this.lstAttrValue is an Array with the attributs values like 'myCheckbox' or 'true'.

Here is my code :

```
Component("Input", {
    add: function(element, type) {
       html = $('<'+this.nomRoot+' type="'+ type +'" />').appendTo('#'+element);

       for(key in this.lstAttr) {
          alert(this.lstAttr[key]);
          alert(this.lstAttrValue[key]);
          $(html).attr("'"+this.lstAttr[key]+"', '"+this.lstAttrValue[key]+"'");
       }

    }
});
```

So my code run with firebug but dosen't add the attributs.

I tried something like that :

- this.lstOptions was an array with the attributs and attributs values like "name, myCheckbox"

  ```
  $("<"+this.nomRoot+" />").attr(this.lstOptions).appendTo(element);
  ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to set the attribute and the value, just reference the two indexes. No need to build some sort of string.

```
$(html).attr(this.lstAttr[key], this.lstAttrValue[key]);
```